# Что происходит, если размер бинарного файла после компиляции программы превышает объем памяти в системе

Tags: память, железо

Например, пусть в системе 8 КБ памяти. После компиляции программы каждая машинная инструкция занимает 4 байта. Этого хватит на 256*8 = 2048 команд. Что будет, если в такой машине запустить программу, которая после компиляции составляет 2050 машинных команд?

Программу в память грузит Операционная система. Допустим, я написал программку на своем ноутбуке, оперативная память в котором составляет 4 Гб, в Visual Studio на C++. И получилось в ней много-много строк. Пытаюсь ее выполнить, а памяти не хватает. Что же мне, теперь нельзя писать большие программы?

Comment: @D-side, ОС будет грузить. А какие варианты?

Comment: Во-от, ответ уже зависит от ОС. И что если если эта программа... и есть ОС? :) А ещё важно уточнить, о какой памяти речь.

Comment: @D-side, об оперативной памяти. По идее, ОС сама же себя и грузит.. не знаю что произойдет.

Comment: @D-side, не думал что они существенные) дополнил вопрос.

Comment: В принципе можно написать и ядро ОС, которое по мере необходимости подгружает-выгружает свои части (однако, какая-то его часть в любом случае будет резидентной), но этим давно уже никто не занимается, поскольку теперь памяти действительно много. / А такие большие программы, которые не влезают в память и в самом деле лучше не писать.

Answer (score 2):

За этим делом следит [Менеджер памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) ОС, в чьи обязанности входит умерить аппетит прожорливых программ, за счет сбрасывания "кусков" оперативной памяти в файл/раздел подкачки ([SWAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86)), и последующем доступе к ним при необходимости.